# Path not fully filled OnDraw Android

Tags: android, paint, draw, shapes

I am working with a shape on my activity, a quadrilateral.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    paint.setAlpha(150);
    // paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.parseColor("#20ffffff"), Color.TRANSPARENT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

    Point point1_draw = new Point(0, 0);
    Point point2_draw = new Point(DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenWidth() * 2, 0);
    Point point3_draw = new Point((DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenWidth()), (DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenHeight() / 8) * 5);
    Point point4_draw = new Point((DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenWidth() / 8) * 3, DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenHeight());
    Point point5_draw = new Point(0, DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenHeight());

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    path.moveTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point2_draw.x, point2_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point3_draw.x, point3_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point4_draw.x, point4_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point5_draw.x, point5_draw.y);
    path.lineTo(point1_draw.x, point1_draw.y);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

My problem is the Point 2 : 
The fill stop at the edge screen and doesn't fill the shape totally. it's stop at **ScreenWidth** instead of **ScreenWidth * 2**
Only the visible part of she shape on the screen takes the white color.

So when do a TranslationX on the shape, it's cut..

Anyone know how to force the drawing of the full shape and not only the visible part of it ?

Comment: What have you done to make the canvas in question larger than the screen?

Comment: You could definitely draw to a bitmap, the size of your choice, then blat to this canvas.

Comment: Point point2_draw = new Point(DisplayUtil.getInstance().getScreenWidth() * 2, 0);

this means the canvas will be drawn outside the screen

Comment: Yes, but are you expecting the canvas to expand because you asked it to draw outside of its bounds? "The fill stop at the edge screen" What else should can it do?